# Save the state of page. Cookie or session?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, cherrypy

I have a little web app (which only has 1 page) that allows user to input and select some options. The input texts and selections will be displayed in another div in the form of table. You may want to refer to the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/xaKXM/5/ 
In this fiddle, you can type anything and after you clicked `submit` it will get the text input and append them to another table `#configtableTable`

```
$('#labels #labelTable tr:last').after(addmore);
$('#configtable #configtableTable tr:last').after(displaymore);
```

I'm using cherrypy as a mini web server (and thus major codes are written in python) and i know that it has `session` [here](http://www.cherrypy.org/chrome/common/2.2/docs/book/chunk/ch03.html) but i have no idea how to use it at all as the example given is not really what i want to see.

FYI, i'm **not** using PHP at all and everything is in a single page. i simply show and hide them. But I want the page to remain as showing `#configtableTable` and hiding `#labelTable` even after refresh. Note that the fiddle is just part of the web app which will only show all these after getting a reply from another device.

Not sure about cookie because all the [links](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) i've found seem broken. How about [jQuery session](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin)? Is it applicable in my case? I need some examples of application though :(

okay, to conclude my questions:
1. can i save the page state after refresh? and how? which of the methods mention above is worth trying? is there any examples for me to refer? or any other suggestions?
2. can i simply **DISABLE** refresh or back after reaching a page?

Thanks everyone in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't disable Refresh and / or back navigation.** It's a terrible idea - user's have a certain expectation of what actions those buttons will perform and modifying that leads to a bad user experience.

As for saving state, while you could use session or cookies, if you don't need that data server side, you can save the state on client side as well.

For example, you could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage)

Alternatively, you could create an object out of the data in the table, `JSON.stringify()` it and append it to the url like this: `example.com#stateData`.

In case of either option, at page load, you'd have to check if there is state data. if you find there is, then use it to recreate the table, instead of displaying the form.

The disadvantage of the first, is that [not all browsers support localStorage](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage).
The disadvantage of the second is that URLs have a length limit and so this solution won't necessarily work for you if you're expecting large amounts of data.

*EDIT*
It appears that Midori [does support most HTML5 features including localStorage however, it's turned off by default.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/372/can-i-speed-up-web-browsing-on-the-raspberry-pi). (*I'm trying to find a better reference*). If you can, just point Midori to [html5test](http://html5test.com/) to see what HTML5 features it supports.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions :) I would expect quite some data as the table in my fiddle example above is just half of the application (i have another half like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qJdaA/2/) and user can add up to more than 10 rows. furthermore, as i'm using raspberrypi, the browser will most probably be `Midori`, not sure if it will support that :(

Comment: so for localstorage, (as seen in the example)i can save the the set data by this `var field = document.getElementById("field");' where `"field"` will be the ID for each text input that i have? but there are so many of them >< and the tables are dynamic :s everything seems so complicated to me :(

Comment: You'd make life a lot easier for yourself by using a javascript framework. I'd recommend Zepto.js since it is very small, and you only need to support one browser.

Comment: okay thanks for your suggestions! they mean a lot! :) will study on localStorage before asking more.

Comment: No worries. If I've answered your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking on the check mark to the left.